# Golang: io.Reader w/io.NopCloser

Tags: go

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working... it returns a `404`... however it works when I remove `io.NopCloser`

**200:**  `req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)`

**404:** `req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, io.NopCloser(body))`

Why does this matter? Because while the signature of `NewRequest` accepts `io.Reader` inside the method its converted to a `io.ReadCloser`

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e94f7df957b6cfbdfbed7092fd05628452c5e018/src/net/http/request.go#L873

```golang
    rc, ok := body.(io.ReadCloser)
    if !ok && body != nil {
        rc = io.NopCloser(body)
    }
```

Additionally the property `Request.Body` is of type `io.ReadCloser` (not `io.Reader`)

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e94f7df957b6cfbdfbed7092fd05628452c5e018/src/net/http/request.go#L182

Ultimately my goal is to acheive this... hence why I do not want to set body when calling `http.NewRequest`

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, nil)

if someCondition {
    req.Body = getBody()//some method that returns a io.ReaderCloser
}

//the real getBody method is more complex than this...
func getBody() io.ReaderCloser {
    data := map[string][]string{
        "scope":         {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"},
        "client_id":     {"0000-0000-0000-0000"},
        "client_secret": {"REDACTED_CLIENT_SECRET"},
        "grant_type":    {"client_credentials"},
    }

    return io.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(url.Values(data).Encode()))
}
```

Complete code that returns a `404` below...

```golang
    uri := "https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    data := map[string][]string{
        "scope":         {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"},
        "client_id":     {"0000-0000-0000-0000"},
        "client_secret": {"REDACTED_CLIENT_SECRET"},
        "grant_type":    {"client_credentials"},
    }

    body := strings.NewReader(url.Values(data).Encode())

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, io.NopCloser(body))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    b, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: It is very unusual to supply a request body for at GET request.  Did you mean to use a POST request?

Comment: As stated it works if I don't wrap body like so: `io.NopCloser(body)`, so while unusual its still valid.... also I did try POST and same result. Also doing this in Postman works with a GET and returns the `access_token`

Comment: Would be more useful if 1) you would tell us what are you trying to achieve and 2) provide as small a code snippet as possible to reproduce the issue

Comment: both of those are already explicitly addressed in the original post...

Comment: 1) The code snippet below `Ultimately my goal is to acheive this... hence why I do not want to set body when calling http.NewRequest` is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: 2) the code below the line `Complete code that returns a 404 below...` is the smallest possible

Comment: I'm afraid since it's an auth call against a redacted endpoint,  this will be impossible for anyone else to reproduce.   Have you tried this against a test http server or service and tried to reproduce?

Comment: NewRequest sets Request.GetBody and Request.ContentLength for common standard library types including strings.Reader.  These fields are not set when the application wraps the strings.Reader with the NOP closer or when the application sets the request body directly.   Does the server respond with a redirect?

Comment: @Zombo... thank you! I set `req.ContentLength` manually and now its working. I did not need to set `GetBody`.